# Winterbash 2016

Tags: discussion, event, winterbash

I've been notified that [Winterbash 2016](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/) is getting close.
"We" opted in the [last times](http://stackpromos.com/promos/16/winter-bash-2015) this was available. Most probably we will opt in again, but I have to ask the community first.
So, do we want hats?  Yey or Ney?

Comment: Yey. I like hats.

Comment: Yey.Yey.Yey.....

Comment: I don't need hat, winter is so `chill`. i need `sweater & cup of coffe` :)

Comment: Yey.Yey......................

Comment: "Winter Is Coming". Better have a hat. So a BIG yeeeyyyyyy.

Comment: Yey.............:)

Comment: Yey, it's always much fun!

Comment: Never heard about Winterbash before, sounds fun I'm in

Comment: Yey................................

Comment: Yey......................

Comment: Yes@Marius, i like hats, i want those.

Comment: Yey ... Yey ...

Comment: Yay!Yay!Yay!Yay!

Comment: yeaaa .........

Comment: Yey.........................

Comment: yeyeyeyeyeyeye...

Comment: Yey............

Comment: of course....!!!

Comment: Ney............

Comment: @ToanNguyen. Kind of late with the ney. It already started. If you don't like hats you can deactivate them from your account.

Comment: @Marius When it will start again?

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara Hold your horses. It's just the beginning of November. I will let the community know when we can opt in or out.

Comment: @Marius, yeah sure. but what is Hold your horses....it means?

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara It's an expression. It means "be patient" or "wait a minute": https://www.google.ro/search?q=hold+your+horses+meaning&oq=hold+your+hors&aqs=chrome.1.0l2j69i57j0l3.2672j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @Marius, ok sir. thanks for replied.